# OAuth 2.0 Twitter questions

Tags: amazon-web-services, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I've gotten access to a twitter elevated access account for my project but I need to get a callback URI and a website URL in order to get read and write privilege's on my twitter bot. I then created an AWS account and server but I don't know exactly where to find the URI and URL. Also I'm trying to run my python script for my twitter bot on my AWS server can anyone please point me in the right direction in order to do this?

Thank you!